# Powershell output redirection not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to call `docker` from a powershell script, but for some reason powershell prints a NativeCommandError  everytime I do, even though I'm redirecting output:

```
PS> docker build -f .\Proj\Dockerfile . 2>&1
docker : #2 [internal] load .dockerignore
At line:1 char:1
+ docker build -f .\Proj\Dockerfile . 2>&1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (#2 [internal] load .dockerignore:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Why redirection is not working? Running powershell 5.1.

Comment: Not actually. I'm not using an IDE, this happens on pure powershell, inside a .PS1 file. The only thing is that I'm inside a function. Also, I'm redirecting the output and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting the error stream to the success stream (`2>&1`), but the success stream will still be printed to console, and error records printed as errors. To actually discard the streams, redirect to null:

```bsh
docker build -f .\Proj\Dockerfile . 2>&1 | Out-Null
# or 
docker build -f .\Proj\Dockerfile . 2>&1 > $null
```